# Add ajax calendar extender to my web form

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to add Ajax Calender extender control to my webform. I added downloaded the latest version ajax and copy it to my application bin folder.When i run my application the date control is not dispay. Am using VS2012 EXPRESS.Does any one know what am doing
 wrong?  I have look at several sample but is still not working for me.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Add-treatment.aspx.cs"       Inherits="Practice_project.Account.Add_treatment" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"   TagPrefix="asp" %>    



<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <header>
        <img src="../Images/Gambia_Coat_of_Arms.jpg" />
    </header>
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Add treatment for the Patient
            </legend>
            <ol>
                <li>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_treatment" runat="server">Treatment</asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="treatment_id" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <%--<asp:CompareValidator runat ="server"></asp:CompareValidator>--%>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <asp:Label ID="No1" runat="server">Nº Days on F75</asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="f75" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="No2">Nº Days on F100</asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="f100" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <asp:Label ID="No3" runat="server">Nº Days on RUTF</asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="rutf" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                </li>
                <li>
                    <asp:Label ID="No4" runat="server">Type RUTF</asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ruft_type" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <asp:Label ID="No5" runat="server">Nº Days on Weaning Foods</asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="wfood" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                </li>
                <li>
                    <asp:Label ID="discharge" runat="server">Date of Discharge</asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="discharge_date" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
                    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>



                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="discharge_date" PopupButtonID="Image1" ></asp:CalendarExtender>
                </li>


            </ol>


        </fieldset>

    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally notice my mistake.Here is is the working one:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>    

<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender runat="server" StartDate="1912-01-01" TargetControlID="discharge_date"  ></ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
```